# Please wait for the User Profile Service

Tags: login

Windows 2019.  Working perfectly, then I installed SQL server 2017.  It rebooted once, and after that, the next boot is stuck at "Please wait for the User Profile Service" after I enter my password.

There are no tools to fix this if I reboot with the DVD.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried logging into a different user account?  Or you could try creating a new account and see if that makes any difference.  [This technique](https://superuser.com/a/247953/96662) allows you to bring up a command-line window before logging in, so you could use it to create a new account if you aren't in a domain, or to bring up event viewer and/or other troubleshooting tools if creating a new account doesn't help.

Comment: Could not get past the login screen to do that.

Comment: That's why I pointed you to an answer explaining a technique that allows you to create user accounts without having to log in first!

Comment: Very good. I'll do it.